# When using puppeteer, is it faster to open a new page after launching the browser, or should I try and use the current tab that gets loaded

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Here's my current code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({...});
const page = await browser.newPage();
```

and then i do all my puppeteer stuff. The issue is, this opens 2 tabs: one when the browser gets launched, and one when you call the newpage function. Would it be faster/worthwhile to do this instead?

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({...});

const getPages = await browser.pages();
const page = getPages[0];
```

This loads the browser and accesses the tab that is already open. Is this better practice or does it not really make a difference?

Comment: If you want you could measure it with `console.time('time'); /* ... */ console.timeEnd('time');`. But i would choose option one. Its more easy to read and in the docs. i would be too lazy to read the docs and find the part that ensures me the browser always opens with an empty page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to work with first-page instead of opening a new one, It's faster than opening a new page, but I don't think that really can boost performance and speed.

```
const [ page ] = await browser.pages();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are loading multiple pages it is recommended to use the `context` API (see [here for docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.19.0&show=api-class-browsercontext)):

```
// Create a new incognito browser context
const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
// Create a new page inside context.
const page = await context.newPage();
// ... do stuff with page ...
await page.goto('https://example.com');
// Dispose context once it's no longer needed.
await context.close();
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all.